# Make a python script work on IIS 8

Tags: python, iis, cgi

I added this to the handler module on IIS for my website

```
Request Path: *.py
Executable: "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\python.exe"
Name: Python
```

I gave permissions for the IIS user to this path C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\

I then made this test.py file to test my configuration

```
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("")
print("""\
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
""")
```

But then I got this Bad Gateway error when I try to load it by http://localhost/test.py

```
The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are:""
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Send a content-length as well. otherwise the http parser on your side does not know where the response ends.

Comment: I added `print('Content-Length: 0')` but I get the same error

Comment: Well... The content length should be the content's length which is not 0.

Comment: How can I calculate the content length? I put it to 420 and still the same error.

Comment: see my answer and the link especially.

Comment: It didn't work either. I think I might have a configuration error. Will try other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [Microsoft's manual](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/276494) (described in more detail in the link):

- Make sure that the Web site containing the Python scripts has an application set up
- Verify that application mapping for .py files is set up
- Verify that the file and directory permissions are set correctly in the computer's access control list (ACL).

And the test response (python 2, conversion should be easy enough):

```
print
print 'Status: 200 OK'
print 'Content-type: text/html'
print

print '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Python Sample CGI</TITLE></HEAD>'
print '<BODY>'
print '<H1>This is a header</H1>'

print '<p>' #this is a comment
print 'See this is just like most other HTML'
print '<br>'
print '</BODY>'
```

Seems like the `Content-Length` header is added for you and you should add a `Status` header.

Comment: Any ideas as to why this would have stopped working on IIS 10? I'm sing the exact steps in the Microsoft link, but on IIS 10 with the .py converted to Python 3.